# Latest updates kubuntu 18.04 2 external monitors not working

Tags: updates, kubuntu, 18.04, multiple-monitors

I have a Lenovo laptop with 2 external monitors. 1 x 4K connected to thunderbolt and an HDMI. These were both working and since updating they have stopped working. When I plug the HDMI monitor in, screens go blank and the HDMI comes on, but the 4K goes off. When I unplug the HDMI the 4K monitors comes back on. Any ideas how to debug/resolve ?

Comment: Somehow I managed to get this working with `xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 1920x1080` ... but Ubuntu's ability to detect these monitors is unstable. It requires playing with the order in which they are connected and `xrandr`